# Grub Command Line screen Dell Laptop

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grub

I have just completed a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after removing the USB, if now displaying following black screen with the message

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.
```

Can anyone assist as it should be showing the user login that I have setup? If I untick the encryption option I dont get the grub command line.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  What model Dell. Dell often requires UEFI update & if SSD, SSD firmware updates. How to Install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en